# What causes the "stretched arms" effect?

Tags: effects, robocop

Near the end of Robocop, as the bad guy is falling, his arms infamously looked stretched out and fake (at 1:29 in this clip):

What type of special effect is causing this? I thought that scenes like this were typically done with a green screen, but I don't see why a green screen would cause the arms to look distorted.

At first I thought it might be a dummy that was being filmed actually falling; but the movements of the character make that unlikely.

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like an early CGI creation...and not a convincing one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was part really bad claymation, part a really bad CGI.